# CICS region automatically restarts after being shutdown

Tags: mainframe, cics, tivoli-system-automation-zos

It wont let me kill the winning vote (the top one), see below:

```
    ,Cmd: ,C,cancel request  ,K, Kill request   ,S,show request details
    ,Cmd Action WIN Request/Vote Data
    ,--- ------ --- ----------------------------------------------------------------

,  ,,START   Y ,Vote       :,MakeAvailable
,  ,,           From Req.  :,MakeAvailable for TCPIP/APL/DEVP
,  ,,           Created    :,2018-11-14  21:03:02
,  ,,           Originator :,OPERATOR(XTSG101)
,  ,,           Priority   :,02740000     Must Be Up - Operator



,  ,,STOP    * ,Request    :,MakeUnAvailable
,  ,,           Created    :,2018-06-01  15:13:56
,  ,,           Originator :,AUTOOPS(AUTOPCR)
,  ,,           Priority   :,02620000     Must Be Down - Automation
,  ,,           Status     :,Losing/Satisfied
```

Comment: is there a question here?

Comment: What technologies are involved / setup?  What automation is being used?  what are you trying to do ?

Comment: Michael - you'll need to add more detail. This is IBM's Tivoli System Automation INGVOTE panel? How are you trying to remove the MakeAvailable vote? what error are you getting? 'It won't let me' isn't really telling us much :-)

Comment: If you shut this CICS region manually, and the winning vite is a makeAvailable, then as soon as SA sees it stop it’ll simply start it again, hence the automatic restarts.